Distributed newton optimization algorithm for m x n dimension
newton optimization algorithm to find the local minimum x∗ of a non-linear function f(x)  with iteration sequence of x0→x1→x2...→x∗  all ∇2f(x_{k}).
considering the x has m, and n with an index of i and j respectively.
I would like to know how to make the matrix of ∇2f(x{i,j}{i}{k}) for each element i and j to calculate the updated matrix values:
x_{i,j}{k+1} = x_{i,j} * alpha * (∇2f(x{i,j}{i}{k}))^-1 * ∇f(x{i,j}{i}{k})

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
